# Change @ApiParam based on Custom AOP Annotation

Tags: spring, aspectj, spring-aop

I have a fairly simple Aspect

**Auditable:**

```java
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface Auditable {}
```

**AuditAspect:**

```java
@Aspect
@Service
class Audit {
    @Pointcut("@annotation(Auditable)")
    void auditableDefinition() {
    }

    @Before("auditableDefinition() && execution(* *(..)) && etc.")
    void auditMethod(a bunch of args) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

This works fine.  But I have an interface which looks something like this:

```java
@RequestMapping( method=RequestMethod.GET, .... )
@Auditable
ResponseEntity<Object> get(

    @RequestParam(required = true)
    @ApiParam(value = Constants.MY_CONST, required = true)
    final String name) {

    //
    // Code here
    //
}
```

The RequestParam and ApiParam is where my question is.  The AuditApect is circumventented with a true/false flag in the `auditMethod` or I can put it in the `auditableDefinition` method.  Is there a way for me to change the parameter requirement in the REST call depending on whether or not the Aspect is enabled or disabled?  I don't know much about this at all, it's inherited code.

Comment: I would like to help, but your questions are unclear and the code does not speak for itself because the crucial parts are missing. So please either improve the sample code so as to make it speak for itself or ask clear questions.

Comment: @kriegaex I apologize, I've tried to copy what I could but I guess I just have to get a better understanding of AOP.  Basically I want to dynamically change the `@RequestParam(required = true)` to `required = false` depending on whether or not an object is Auditable, i.e. `@Auditable` is configured.

Comment: Even if it was possible (it is not), I would not do it because you would never know when and where in the Spring lifecycle the annotation parameter value gets accessed, before or after your advice kicks in. Annotations are static information created by the compiler and for a reason require constant, static parameter values. Please describe **what** you want to achieve and show relevant code instead of describing **how** you imagine you want to achieve it. This is a common mistake: People are fixated on a technical way to solve a problem, unnecessarily narrowing solution option scope.